# Record screen and audio then generate to one video file in java.

Tags: audio, screen, record, jmf

I am writting a program as http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/. I used applet and import jmf.jar to my project. When I use it, it couldn't get anything capture devices so it couldn't capture audio and video. 
 I captured screen to video but it hadn't sound. I captured sound but it hadn't video. I use jmf to merger 2 stream to video file. But it error. 
 Everybody can help me to resol problem. Thanks your help.

Comment: what you tried ? means how you did capturing video recording?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xuggle-Xuggler http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/introduction-xuggler-video-manipulation.html API which is wrapper of FFmpeg command line tool. Both are open source.